# A TestNg Multithreading Issue. TestNg does not respect the child threads

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have a very simple class that asynchronously writes a list to a file :

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public enum FileOps {
    INSTANCE;

    private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    private AtomicInteger fileCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private <T> void writeListToFile(String fileName, List<T> obj) {
        FileWriter writer = null;
        Type tType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4376511240656742709L;
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
            writer.append(gson.toJson(obj, tType));
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public <T> void asynWriteListToFile(List<T> obj){
        threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String fileName = "C:\\data\\" + fileCount.incrementAndGet() + "_data.txt";
                System.out.println(fileName);
                FileOps.INSTANCE.writeListToFile(fileName, obj);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I have written a unit test for this class using TestNg

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FileOpsTest {

    @Test
    public void asynWriteListToFile() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            FileOps.INSTANCE.asynWriteListToFile(list);
        }

    }
}
```

I have a weird situation. In my TestNg execution some how the testing engine does not wait for the child threads to finish. So I am expecting 10000 files written on a disk, but every time I saw less files written on a disk. However if I write a client using a main method, everything works fine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileOpsClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            FileOps.INSTANCE.asynWriteListToFile(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow testNg engine shuts down my thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the files are written asynchronously, `FileOpsTest.asynWriteListToFile()` ends before the files are all written and org.testng.TestNG (or your IDE's test runner) calls `System.exit(int)` (e.g. [`TestNG.java:1375`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/44f890ad06a6a76bd47cc86b8b0d1c0612ce623b/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java#L1375)).

In contrast, `FileOpsClient.main(String[])` does not explicitly call `System.exit(int)` and as such the JVM waits for your threads to end because they are not daemon threads. See [How to make TestNG wait for my test to complete before shutting it down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30205936/3255152) for more details.

In you're case, you could make some changes so that your test can effectively invoke `threadPool.awaitTermination(long, TimeUnit)` (e.g. making `FileOps.threadPool` "package local" instead of "private" and accessing it from your test, adding a method on `FileOps` to do so for you and keep `FileOps.threadPool` "private", etc.).

However, if your goal is to unit test then I would suggest that an `ExecutorService` is an "awkward collaborator" and that you should refactor your code so that 1) you can test spawning threads using a mocked `ExecutorService` (see [How to unit test that ExecutorService spawns new thread for task?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669453/3255152)), 2) you can test the actual writing of a list to files logic independent of how such gets created as an asynchronous task, and 3) don't use `FileWriter` directly but simply use a `Writer` so that you can also slip a mock when testing and avoid actually writing/reading files in your unit tests and leave such an exercise to integration tests if needed.

Comment: The critics for not using FileWriter directly instead inject the abstract Writer type to the method for mocking and for more testable code changes the way I have looked to unit tests. It was a epiphany. Thanks.